# How do I stop characters sent to PuTTY screwing with its title/output?

Tags: c++, json

I'm sending JSON to PuTTY on Windows from a C++ program running on an mbed.

I've escaped the characters `\`, `/`, `"`, `\b`, `\n`, `\f`, `\r`, `\t` as per json.org.

But I still have three quirks that I do not understand:

1. Window title changes to part of the output. Sometimes.
2. Cursor skips 'up' and starts overwriting what was there.
3. Line breaks that are like `\n`, except horizontal position is kept from above line.

I thought (3) might be `\v`, but escaping this did not help, and further, JSON spec doesn't ask us to escape it.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: 3 is because `\r\n` means carriage return (return to beginning of line) followed by newline (move a line down) probably the cause of 2 as well

Comment: @ratchetfreak Oh and it is a single `char`? So not caught by the two separately? But your description sounds exactly like `\n` alone - these line breaks are *not* returning to beginning of line.

Comment: actually that is the 2 chars in sequence, having just 1 will cause returning back to the start of current line or jump down a line as appropriate. modern text editors know how to handle the lone chars

Comment: I included that `case` but it's made no difference. To any of the three.

Comment: I am not sure why that would cause *upwards* vertical movement, either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find that it's not your application, but the actual terminal emulation that putty is using.

There are a couple ways you can mitigate this.

1) If it's just the title getting screwed up your worried about, then simply disable the remote client from changing the title.

Open Putty, and go to "Terminal->Features" in the side menu, on this page you'll find "Disable remote controlled window title changing", tick that and you'll have no more problems.

2) If it's something more, then you'll need to have a dig around in the "Terminal" and "Window" settings sections.

The window settings in particular have a number of places that you can change that will affect how Putty responds to what it believes are control codes.

In Window->Translation for example, you can force the remote character set, or tell putty to use "+-=" as line drawing symbols rather than the ms-dos box drawing set.

In "Terminal->Keyboard" you can change how putty deals with various incoming char sequences.

I don't know how long you've been working in I.T, but long before the days of windows and HTTP and JSON everything that was performed by a terminal was controlled by "Control Codes"

The first chart here : [Ascii Chart](http://www.asciitable.com/)

You can see that all the codes before 32 had/have a special meaning.

Some such as tab (Ctrl code 9) and carriage return (Ctrl code 13) are still used today, but many are not.  Add to this the ANSI control code standard

See here: [Ansi Escape Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) and here : [VT100 codes](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) which where often used to make text based works of art for BBS Systems (see here: [Ansi Art on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_art))

and the result is a bit of a mix-mash that terminals like Putty will still try to interpret in today's world of rich multimedia.

Things like JSON can produce sequences of characters that at times can confuse Putty into thinking it's receiving strings to be acted on, but which have missing data.  Like any decent terminal emulation it will often do the best it can with what it receives and get it wrong at times.

This is why I think, the solution to your question lies in tweaking things like the terminal response settings in order to make putty not react to things so harshly.

Comment: Thanks, I had already disabled the title option - however this just stopped it changing the title, it didn't force it to stay in the output window as expected.

Comment: Yea sometimes it can be a bit of trial and error, I often have a similar issue when using linux apps such as Midnight Commander and others that use 'Curses' for output when I'm connecting to servers using putty. You might also want to play with the keyboard sequences under "Terminal->Keyboard" too, that often helps.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in your output is the sequence of characters that changes the terminal's hard status line, which PuTTY displays as its title.  On many terminals, that sequence is

```
ESC ] 0 ; TitleString BEL
```

where `ESC` and `BEL` are the ASCII escape and bell characters.

The other odd behavior is caused by similar sequences.

I would suggest running your output through `od` or something like it to see if there are unprintable characters in it.

Comment: Many thanks for that. But with that in mind, should I not tamper with it? It is only an issue because of the particular tool (PuTTY) I'm using to view the string, I suppose I shouldn't modify the string just to fix it for PuTTY, and stick to fixing only those mentioned above from the JSON spec?

Comment: @OllieFord:  If the JSON spec says you shouldn't have unprintable characters in the stream, then you should fix those characters so they're properly escaped.  If it doesn't and all you're using PuTTY for is debugging, I'd just live with it.